# what does it mean to have an SQL FROM clause with no comma?

Tags: sql, syntax

I noticed today that this query

```
 select * from table1 table2 where column_from_table1 = ?;
```

works.  It works the same as (same columns return)

```
 select * from table1 where column_from_table1 = ?;
```

Shouldn't the former be a syntax error?  What is it interpreting `table2` as?

Comment: For the record, you never want to use commas in the `from` clause anyway.  You should be using proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table1 table2 where column_from_table1 = ?;
```

`table2` is working as a table alias for `table1`. It's not being used as the name of an object in the database at all.  The fact that a table named `table2` exists is *wholly irrelevant* to this query. Usually you'd see something like this:

```
select t.id, t.name from table1 t where t.column_from_table1 = ?;
```

Some RDBMSs require the `as` keyword, so you'll also see this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name FROM table1 AS t WHERE t.column_from_table1 = ?;
```

Table aliases are useful for making queries with multiple tables easier to write, especially if they have shared column names which need to be qualified. They're also essential for self-joins where a table is joined to itself.

Example of a join using aliases:

```
SELECT t1.Id,
    t1.Name as t1_Name
    t2.Name as t2_Name
FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.column_from_table1 = ?;
```

Or, for a self-join to look for duplicate `Name` values, for example:

```
SELECT t1.Name,
    t1.Id
    t2.Id as Dupe_Id
FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table1 t2
        ON t1.Name = t2.Name
WHERE t1.Id < t2.Id;
```

Notice that this query is referring to `table1` twice and uses the aliases of `t1` and `t2` to differentiate which it's referring to.

Note that a comma join, such as `FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id` is very old syntax that should be explicitly avoided when writing queries. The older syntax is difficult to read and maintain and doesn't support outer joins except by vender-specific extensions. The newer syntax with the `JOIN` keyword was introduced in standard SQL in 1992. There's no reason to still be using comma joins.

Answer (score 3):

Appears it's interpreting it as renaming the table, even though `table2` exists it happily allows the rename, this also works:

```
 select * from table1 asdf where asdf.column_from_table1 = ?;
```

Comment: Almost funny that if you qualified the where clause as table1.column_from_table1 you would have received the error you were expecting.  Very dirty query